# Live XML truck fleet GPS data To ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, xml

Currently I have access to truck fleet data through Telogis Fleet. Telogis provides an XML feed and I would like to know how I can feed that into ArcGIS that is continuously updated?

Comment: I am looking for a solution to be able to see all fleets on a web map and have the data stored in a feature class.

Answer (score 2):

You will need something to process the XML into a format that ArcGIS can consume. This probably means using an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool such as [FME](http://www.safe.com/fme) or custom programming.

You'll also need something to display the data in (near) realtime, which ArcGIS doesn't do out of the box. ESRI offers [Tracking Analyst Extension for ArcGIS Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_Tracking_Analyst/006300000001000000/), [Tracking Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/tracking-server/10.1/index.html#//00r60000000r000000) and the [GeoEvents Processor extension for ArcGIS Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions/geoevent-extension), which you may want to look into, but are additional costs.

You might also be able to program a [custom extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000001v000000) or [add-in](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w2000000) for ArcMap to handle this.

Perhaps you can clarify what sort of solution you are looking for.

Comment: I second a GeoEvents Processor.